# node.js request to http string

Tags: node.js, http

I'm using the request module to send http requests from my server.

I want to be able to intercept the request before it is sent and save it as a raw http request text.

There are GUI tools such as burp suite that will act as a proxy server and intercept outgoing requests in raw HTTP text, but I need to be able to do this in my node server.

So far my efforts to convert a request object to raw string has been futile and I'm pretty sure there are better ways to do so but I'm stuck.

Thanks

Comment: if you're sending a request, surely you know the url and its parameters already?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-debug

Comment: True. However, in order to get the exact outgoing http message text I thought it would be better to be able to intercept the actual request message than to try to construct a string from the parameters of the request  myself. Is that reasonable?